# Output ELKI PCA result as text

Tags: elki

Can I use ELKI to just do PCA on my input dataset and get the transformed set as text file? The output format of the file does not really matter.

 I see PCA is not available as an algorithm but only as a dbc.filter. I tried invoking the NullAlgorithm after the PCA filter and then the ResultWriter but it does not output the data set (which is not surprising since it returns `null` as a Result). 
Maybe an algorithm that passes through the results from the filter would be a convenient functionality? Since I'm not yet comfortable at all with the code, maybe somebody could point me to the steps I need to take to implement something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use the algorithm

> `-algorithm clustering.trivial.TrivialAllInOne`

to cause the default result writer to dump your data. The `NullAlgorithm` does not work, because the result writer then is not sure what to write. If it sees a clustering result with a single cluster named `cluster`, it will  write it to a file `cluster.txt`.

I occasionally use this to project data, too. On the long run, I would love to see ELKI be extended with a nice preprocessing interface.